# Resizabble rubber band doesn't resize with QmainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt5, window-resize

For an AI application, I need to define some overlays over images.

I am using the following code to draw a resizable rubberband on an image (Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/11021720/vesa95 and https://stackoverflow.com/users/11162165/nathancy).

My problem is that when I resize the main window, the rubberband doesn't resize.

I have added a resize envent on the main window but the problem remains.

What did I missed ?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class ResizableRubberBand(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ResizableRubberBand, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.parentWidth = parent.width()
        self.parentHeight = parent.height()
        self.draggable = True
        self.dragging_threshold = 5
        self.mousePressPos = None
        self.mouseMovePos = None
        
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.SubWindow)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QSizeGrip(self), 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        self._band = QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self._band.show()
        self.show()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self._band.resize(self.size())

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        # Get current window size
        window_size = self.size()
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        qp.drawRect(0, 0, window_size.width(), window_size.height())
        qp.end()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.draggable and event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
            self.mousePressPos = event.globalPos()                # global
            self.mouseMovePos = event.globalPos() - self.pos()    # local
        super(ResizableRubberBand, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.draggable and event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
            globalPos = event.globalPos()
            moved = globalPos - self.mousePressPos
            if moved.manhattanLength() > self.dragging_threshold:
                # Move when user drag window more than dragging_threshold
                diff = globalPos - self.mouseMovePos
                # Forbids the selection to go out of the frame
                if diff.x() <= 0 or diff.x() > self.parentWidth-self.width() :
                    diff = QtCore.QPoint(0 if diff.x()<=0 else self.parentWidth-self.width(),diff.y())
                if diff.y() <= 0 or diff.y() > self.parentHeight-self.height():
                    diff = QtCore.QPoint(diff.x(), 0 if diff.y()<=0 else self.parentHeight-self.height())
                self.move(diff)
                self.mouseMovePos = globalPos - self.pos()
                
        super(ResizableRubberBand, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.mousePressPos is not None:
            if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
                moved = event.globalPos() - self.mousePressPos
                if moved.manhattanLength() > self.dragging_threshold:
                    # Do not call click event or so on
                    event.ignore()
                self.mousePressPos = None
        super(ResizableRubberBand, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
    


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Show Rubber Band')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('image.JPG'))
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.band = None

        imagePath = r"Linux-Logo.png"
        # Pixmap
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath)
        self.qp = QtGui.QPainter(self.pixmap)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def handleButton(self):
        self.band = ResizableRubberBand(self.label)
        self.band.setGeometry(150, 150, 100, 100)

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QtGui.QResizeEvent):
        if self.band is not None:
            self.band.parentWidth = self.label.width()
            self.band.parentHeight = self.label.height()
        QtWidgets.QWidget.resizeEvent(self, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Test ResizableRubberBand
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(300, 100, 600, 500)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is my issue:

[Rubberband creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXXnq.png)

[Result after resizing the main window => the rubberband has not been resized accordingly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaL4f.png)

Comment: You could make the rubberband a child of the label, which should be subclassed and override its `resizeEvent()`, so that you can use the `oldSize()` and `size()` of the event and eventually update the rubberband using simple proportions.

Comment: I thought the following line was creating the rubberband as a child of the Qlabel :
`self.band = ResizableRubberBand(self.label)`
It seems that I was wrong :( 
So how do I do to declare the rubbberband as a child of the Qlabel ?

Comment: Sorry, I lost that part, but the rest remains: you have to implement the resizing of the rubberband directly from the QLabel (so, you should also probably make the rubberband a *member* of that instance) or at least through an event filter.